# dynamic function using string - python

Tags: python, pandas, function, dynamic

I have seen posts similar to this but not quite.

```
import pandas as pd
dynamic_fun = {
    '.csv': read_csv,
    '.xlsx': read_excel
}
```

I would like to do  something like that :

```
df = pd.(dynamic_fun['.csv'])('Z:/test1.txt', delimiter = "\t")
```

or

```
df = pd.(dynamic_fun)['.csv']('Z:/test1.txt', delimiter = "\t")
```

Instead of something like that:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Z:/test1.txt', delimiter = "\t")
```

Basically change the function dynamically using a dictionary.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
import pandas as pd
dynamic_fun = {
    '.csv': pd.read_csv,
    '.xlsx': pd.read_excel
}

df = dynamic_fun['.csv']('Z:/test1.txt', delimiter = "\t")
```

You need to store the complete reference to the method (including the `pd.`) in the dictionary

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you out.